# About quasi-compact morphisms and points of a quasi-compact

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let X be a quasi-compact scheme and let $x\in X$ be a point. Then we have a induced morphism:
$$Spec\,O_{X,x}\to X$$
My question goes as it follows: $Spec\,O_{X,x}$ is a compact scheme, for it is affine. Is the morphism above a quasi-compact morphism? Why?

Comment: If $X$ is quasi-separated, then yes. Indeed, quasi-separated means that for any affine open subset $U \subset X$, this inclusion is quasi-compact. In particular, if we choose $U$ such that $x \in U$, then your map is the composition of $\operatorname{Spec}\,O_{X,x} \rightarrow U$ (affine) and of $U \subset X$, which is quasi-compact. 
In general, I don’t think that this has to be the case, but I don’t have a good counterexample.

Comment: That's what I thought, and a relief. I consider this question answered, but I can't mark your comment as an answer, how can I do it?

Comment: I’ll turn this comment into an answer in the week-end so you can accept it (or maybe it’ll prompt someone to give a complete counter-example, so maybe you should wait a bit afterwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer.

If $X$ is *quasi-separated*, then yes. Indeed, a quasi-separated scheme is one where the intersection of any two quasi-compact open subsets is quasi-compact.

So let $x \in U$ be affine open, then $U \subset X$ is a quasi-compact open immersion, while $\operatorname{Spec}\,O_{X,x} \rightarrow U$ is affine thus quasi-compact, and therefore $\operatorname{Spec}\,O_{X,x} \rightarrow X$ is quasi-compact.

Quasi-separatedness is a rather weak condition (it always holds for locally Noetherian schemes, for instance), but it’s not automatic.

Here’s an example where the property you seek fails, inspired from Stacks 01KL.

Let $X_1, X_2$ be two copies of the spectrum of the ring $R=k[a_1,\ldots]$ (there are infinitely many variables and $k$ is a field), and $X=X_1 \cup X_2$ where $X_1$ qnd $X_2$ are glued along $X_1 \backslash \{x_1\}=X_2 \backslash \{x_2\}$, with $x_1, x_2$ corresponding to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$.

Take $x=x_1$. Then $\operatorname{Spec}\,O_{X,x} \rightarrow X$ is not quasi-compact: the preimage of $X_2$ is exactly $\operatorname{Spec}\,O_{X,x} \cong \operatorname{Spec}\,R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ minus its closed point, which isn’t quasi-compact.